# Can I loop inside a variable using HTML_Template_Sigma in PHP?

Tags: php, html, pear

I have to use the HTML_Template_Sigma PEAR Module to do an assignment on PHP that basically wraps all the HTML of a website to make templates with it instead of pasting the same HTML over and over. The thing is that all the content is added using variables and at some point I have to loop through an array inside one of the string variables (which has a table inside). So I checked the documentation which is not really abundant and it does have some sort of loop implementation but oriented to publications and I don't know how to use it to solve my problem.

http://www.pixel2life.com/publish/tutorials/13/pear_module_html_template_sigma/

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-template-sigma.intro-syntax.php

Still what they show is not exactly the same as this.

```
  foreach ($data as $result) {

$plantilla->setCurrentBlock('table_row');
$plantilla->setVariable(array(
    'date'  => $result[0],
    'epicentre' => $result[1],
    'region' => $result[2],
    'richter' => $result[3],
    'mercalli' => $result[4]

));
$plantilla->parseCurrentBlock('table_row');
}
```

This is my variable:

```
content = '
   <table>
                      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Epicentre</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Mw Richter</th>
            <th>Mercalli</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<!-- BEGIN table_row -->
    <tr>
<td>{date}</td>
<td>{epicentre}</td>
<td>{region}</td>
<td>{richter}</td>
<td>{mercalli}</td>
</tr>
<!-- END table_row -->
   </tbody>
                </table>';
```

My array contains 5 columns of data. I've tried but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!